# Counting sequences of k elements

Tags: c, algorithm, integer, sequences

If I have two arrays of integers:

`a = {2,2,3,3,5,6,7,2,2,2}`, `b = {6,-5,2,2,2,2,4,5,3,3}`

and an integer `k = 2`, which defines the number of sequences in succession (SAME in both arrays - `[2,2]`, `[3,3]` , `[2,2,2]` in "a" / `[2,2,2,2]` , `[3,3]` in "b" ), how can I run a separate count for each sequence of numbers?

I thought the algorithm in this way:

```
int count = 1;  
for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    if ( a[i] == a[i+1] && b[i] == b[i+1] && a[i] == b[i] ){
        count++;
    }

    if ( count >= k ){
        condition = true;
    }
}
```

Starting "count" by one for every sequence of elements could ensure that the count will be exact, but in this way, when checking the second and third position of the array `a`, it will also count the element `3` instead of stopping at `2`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will overrun the array unless you change to i < N-1 in your loop(assuming N is the size of the arrays)

Comment: @mathematician1975 yes, N is the size of the arrays, i tried to set the for loop with N-1 but , however, it seems not work, because he also count the "3" element , increasing the counting

Comment: What about if(`a[i] == a[i+1] && b[i] == b[i+1] && a[i] == b[i] && count <= k`) ? however it is better to use `count <= k && a[i] == a[i+1] && b[i] == b[i+1] && a[i] == b[i]`

Comment: @NeelBasu if i try this case: `a={2,2,3,3,5,6,7,2,2,2}` and `b={6,-5,2,2,4,5,3,3,2,2}` and `k=3` , it also seems not work.

Comment: @philippe try to give a useful tip?

Comment: @n.m. the function is boolean , if there's the right combination of k-sequencies in both arrays it must be true , else it must be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing your comment "the function is boolean", I guess that you want to find out whether there is a sequence of identical numbers of length `k` or more, that is a sub-sequence of both input arrays.

It seems that the sub-sequence doesn't have to appear at the same position in both arrays (or else the exercise would be less interesting).

Assuming my guesses are right, you can use the following idea:

1. Check all pairs of positions `(p1,p2)`, where `p1` is the position in the first array, and `p2` is a position in the second array.
2. Use the range `0...N-k` for the positions, to avoid overflow (reading past the end of an array)
3. For each pair of positions, check whether the `k` numbers starting at these positions are the same
4. If they are the same for at least one pair of positions, the result is `true`; otherwise `false`

You can use two nested loops to implement (1) and (2), like so:

```
for (p1 = 0; p1 <= N - k; ++p1)
{
    for (p2 = 0; p2 <= N - k; ++p2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can use a separate function or a nested loop to check condition (3).

Comment: You have fully understood what i have to do , thanks for the tip , very useful. :)